# Why the sorting of string using selection sort is not working properly?

Tags: c++, sorting, selection-sort

This code is not giving any syntax error but is has some logical error and I'm unable to find it out.
The Code is :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
void SortString(std::string str, int size)
{
    int min;
    for(int i = 0; i < size-2; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < size-2; j++)
        {
            if( str[j] < str[min] )
                min = j;
        }
        char temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[min];
        str[min] = temp;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl<<str<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cout<<"\n Enter a string to sort : ";
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    std::cout<<"\n String after sorting is : \n";
    SortString(str, strlen(str.c_str()));;
    //std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Few output instances are :

1.
    Enter a string to sort : lovely

```
 String after sorting is : 

elovly
```

2.

```
Enter a string to sort : program

 String after sorting is : 

goprram
```

This same logic works for sorting an integer array. But its not working for string.

Comment: fyi there you can use `std::sort` to sort a `string` : `std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());`

Answer (score 3):

Well the key thing to notice is that if you look at your two examples:

```
lovely ==>
elovly

program ==>
goprram
```

What's it look like it's doing? To me it looks like it's sorting all but the last **two** characters.

What do your loop bounds look like?

```
for(int i = 0; i < size-2; i++)
{
    min = i;
    for(int j = i+1; j < size-2; j++)
```

You're skipping the last two characters! Change the bounds to just `size`.

---

A `std::string` knows its own size, there's a member function for this: `size()` (or `length()`). So you don't need `strlen()`. Then `SortString()` it actually taking a *copy* of the string and sorting it internally, would be much more useful if you sorted the original string by taking it by reference. And lastly, there exists `std::swap()`:

```
void SortString(std::string& str)
{
    int min;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for(int j = i+1; j < str.size(); j++)
        {
            if( str[j] < str[min] )
                min = j;
        }

        std::swap(str[i], str[min]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you count until size - 2? This way you are not seeing the last two characters

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no great sense to declare the second parameter because objects of type `std::string` keep inside themselves the information about their sizes.

Also this condition in the outer loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < size-2; i++)
               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

is wrong. For example if the string has only two characters like `"BA"` then it is obvious that `size` is equal to `2` and the loop will iterate never. That is the characters will not be swapped to get the sorted string `"AB"`.

The function can be written the following way

```
void SortString( std::string str )
{
    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::string::size_type min = i;
        for ( std::string::size_type j = i + 1; j < str.size(); j++ )
        {
            if ( str[j] < str[min] ) min = j;
        }
        if ( i != min ) std::swap( str[i], str[min] );
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << str << std::endl;
}
```